# Data type mismatch in criteria expression Access error

Tags: ms-access, mismatch

In Access, I have several different expressions going (since the code is too long to put into one expression field). Here is an example of the expression:

> ConsultativeSellingScore: (IIf(Eval([CallControl] In
>   (10,5,0)),10,0)+IIf(Eval([QualifiedCallerEligibility] In
>   (10,5,0)),10,0)+IIf(Eval([NextSteps] In
>   (8,4,0)),8,0)+IIf(Eval([NeedsAssessment] In
>   (14,7,0)),14,0)+IIf(Eval([PlanRecommendation] In
>   (14,7,0)),14,0)+IIf(Eval([AskedForSale] In
>   (18,9,0)),18,0)+IIf(Eval([OvercameObjections] In (10,5,0)),10,0))

I have tried reading the articles in regards to the data type mismatch error for Access, but unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong. In the table the field is Number and I have the field criteria for the expression as general number. As you can see in the code, I have also stripped out the quotations from around the numbers, so it shouldn't be viewing the expression as text. If anyone has any idea what the issue is, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

IIf(IsNull([UtilizedScript]),0,6)+IIf(IsNull([GatheredInfo]),0,14)+IIf(IsNull([Hold]),0,6)+IIf(IsNull([CallDisposition]),0,10)+IIf(IsNull([BuiltRapport]),0,10)+IIf(IsNull([EffectiveCommunication]),0,6)+IIf(IsNull([PhoneEtiquette]),0,10)+IIf(IsNull([Ownership]),0,8)+IIf(IsNull([UsedResources]),0,8)+IIf(IsNull([ProfessionalConduct]),0,20)+IIf(IsNull([AccurateInformation]),0,18)+IIf(IsNull([CallControl]),0,10)+IIf(IsNull([QualifiedCallerEligibility]),0,10)+IIf(IsNull([NextSteps]),0,8)+IIf(IsNull([NeedsAssessment]),0,14)+IIf(IsNull([PlanRecommendation]),0,14)+IIf(IsNull([AskedForSale]),0,18)+IIf(IsNull([OvercameObjections]),0,10)

solved my problem- utilized this and the other half of the problem and then did a separate query to calculate the percentage.

Comment: Are all the fields numbers? Do you have any null values? I might be tempted to build a function for this or possibly better store the potential scores in a table and query it.

Comment: Yes, there are null values. I was hoping that the expression would catch those- since 10, 5, and 0 return the result of 10 for the CallControl- then what I wanted was any other value, such as null to return the 0 value. Is that not working properly from what you're stating? I can't get rid of the nulls unfortunately- which is why I'm trying to handle it with this expression- I have two more of these expressions which will be added together & used as the divisor- I want the nulls to become 0 so they aren't factored into the total possible. (I'm creating a % score).

Comment: If you simplify it to just one expression, make sure it has some null values, then test from there. I think EVAL will baulk at nulls, but it's not a function I've used very often tbh.

Comment: I can't make it one expression because Access wasn't accepting how long of an expression it was- gave a message about it not being able to be edited and it would strip the expression out and just make it blank. So that leaves me with 3 separate expressions which I will need to add together to make the total divisor...